# Problema de FireDac (Delphi XE 10.2 e Access 2000)

Tags: delphi, microsoft-access, firedac

Estou usando o Delphi 10.2, e estou a tentar exibir a lista das tabelas de uma base dados Access.

O caminho do meu BD é superior à 128 caracteres...

Caminho do meu BD:

> pathbd  := "C:\basedados.............\dados.mdb" (> 128 caracteres)

Como estou utilizando:

```
var
  FDataBase  : TFDConnection;
begin  
  FDataBase :=  TFDConnection.Create(nil);  
  try        
    FDataBase.DriverName := 'MSACC';    
    FDataBase.Params.Add('Database='+pathbd);
    FDataBase.Params.Add('LoginPrompt=False');
    FDataBase.Params.Add('OpenMode=ReadWrite');    
    FDataBase.GetTableNames('', '', '', Memo.Lines);
  finally   
    FDataBase.free; 
  end;
end;
```

Erro que é retornado:

> "raised exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][DatS]-32.
>   Variable length column [CATALOG_NAME] overflow. Value length - [188],
>   column maximum length - [128]'.

Como posso contornar esse problema?

Comment: Desculpa pela opção obvia, mas há a possibilidade de alterar o diretório do banco? ou abreviar a nomenclatura, tornando o endereço menor?

Comment: Obrigado pela sua intervençao.O problema é isso mesmo, o usuario tem a liberdade de colocar a base de dados sem limitaçoes.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a questão é antiga mas encontrei uma solução simples.
Uso Delphi 10.3
No meu caso o problema estava em uma propriedade do FDMongoQuery
Na sessão FormatOptions defini o parâmetro StrsTrim2Len para true e não tive mais exceções na aplicação.

Comment: Marca como resolvida.

Comment: Sei que não é o seu problema, mas fiquem atento ao formato do banco de dados (ANSI,UTF8 e etc), pois o formato errado pode dar falha no tamanho do campo.